# ML algorithm Representation, Evaluation & Optimization

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, computer-science, theory

I was reading through a paper published by the University of Washington with tips about Machine Learning algorithms.

The way they break down an ML algorithm is into 3 parts. A representation, evaluation and optimization. I would like to understand how these three parts work together, so what is the process like throughout a typical machine learning algorithm.

I understand that my question is very abstract and each algorithm will be different, but if you know of a way to explain it abstractly please do. If not feel free to use a specific algorithm to explain.

Paper: http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~pedrod/papers/cacm12.pdf ~
See Table 1.

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian Raschka has provided a very nice [flowchart](https://github.com/rasbt/pattern_classification/blob/master/PDFs/supervised_learning_flowchart.pdf) of the (supervised) machine learning process.

(I am familiar with text classification, so I will use this as an example)

In short :

1. Representation: Your data needs to be brought into a suitable algorithmic form. For Text classification you would for example extract features from your full text documents (input data) and bring them into a bag-of-words representation.
2. Application of the respective algorithm: Here your algorithm is executed. After training you have to do some kind of evaluation to measure your success (the criteria for evaluation is depending on the task). (*The Evaluation is the final part of this step*)
3. Optimization: The learning algorithms usually have one or more parameters to tune. Having reference pairs of parameter configuration / evaluation (from the previous step) you can now tweak the paramaters and evaluate the effect on your results.
   (In the flowchart this is the edge, where we go back to the step *"Learning algorithm training"*)